# How do I do IE conditionals in CSS?

Tags: css

If I want to add padding based on the browser the user is viewing the page in, is there a way in CSS that I can do something like:

if IE do
padding:5px;
else if not IE do
padding 10px;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a great reference: [Quirksmode.org Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Although the control structure is in the markup and not the CSS, it accomplishes your goal and is usually considered the best practice when serving browser-specific stylesheets.

Comment: Note, IE8 in compatibility more reports itself and processes conditional comments as if it is IE7.

Answer (score 8):

The best-practice way is to have a single stylesheet for IE-only fixes, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie-styles.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then just override specific problem-causing styles in the `ie-styles.css` file.

Answer (score 6):

**Target ALL VERSIONS of IE**

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target everything EXCEPT IE**

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 7 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 6 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 5 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 5]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie5.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 5.5 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 5.5000]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie55.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 6 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 7 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 8 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 6 and HIGHER**

```
<!--[if gt IE 5.5]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 7 and HIGHER**

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 8 and HIGHER**

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

For complete reference on the topic, Chris Coyier: [How To Create an IE-Only Stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 2):

Although the IE conditional can be used only in html and not in the CSS, you can use the following in your CSS files for your quick-and-short tests/hacks.

```
  p {
   /* all browsers */
   background-color: red; 

   /* for IE7 and below - append a * before the property */
   *background-color: blue; 

   /* for IE6 and below - append a _ before the property */
   _background-color: green;
  }
```

While you can use this for your quick and short requirements, I think, you should follow the suggestion by Mark Hurd given above for production-level heavy codes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cleaner way to target **IE 10+** in CSS only

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

  /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */

}
```

(Source: [Phil Newcomer](https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/04/target-internet-explorer-10-11-css/))

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind ugliness in your code, you can use something like the Holly hack:

```
div { padding:5px; }
* html div { padding:10px; }
```

There's a neat CSS Zen Garden example that does this to present two distinct designs, but I don't recall its name.