# How to I make my input fields look the same across the browsers?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a login page with two input fields. In Chrome, Firefox and IE10, they look great, but in IE 7, 8, 9, they are too thin. Here is the HTML and class for the fields.

HTML:

```
<div class="login-input">
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Username is required." id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.login-input input
{
width: 250px;
height: 14px;
}
```

This is how it looks in Chrome, Firefox, IE10 (correct look)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpMDa.png

This is how it looks in IE 7, 8, 9 (incorrect look)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl2dw.png

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem on my website. I solved it by loading a different stylesheet for IE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541982/apply-css-rules-if-browser-is-ie

Comment: try setting a padding value.

Comment: reset css files are sometimes used to have a "start consistant" point that makes the base the same - for instance the default for 1em can vary from browser to browser.

Comment: YOUR code on my IE8 looks exactly like on Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/mnZgS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting values for padding?

Comment: I just removed the height attribute and added padding to the top and bottom of the input field and it looks much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try `box-sizing` to `border-box`, but there is [no support](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) for ie7 for that.

```
input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height in addition to height.

```
.login-input input
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```