# Determine what browser is being used, then style a class dependant on that

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to check what browser the site is being viewed in, and then based upon that change certain elements within a CSS class so that it looks the same on all browsers?

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

EDIT:

Right ok I have gotten it to work in IE and firefox now, but it looks slightly off in chrome....is there some Javascript to detect if I am using chrome, and then based upon this change the margin-bottom of the class #titleAreaBox?

Comment: you can't do that will CSS can I give you an answer on jQuery? or JS?

Comment: Yes that would be helpfull if you can do it in JS

Comment: There are better ways of handling most incompatibilities. Can you be more explicit in your question as to what behavior you are trying to modify, error or effect you are experiencing?

Comment: Don't do this.  Instead, use Modernizr to do _feature detection_.

Comment: check [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/)

Comment: I would read up on the concept of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement), so that the basic features work in older browsers, and you can add CSS3 styling, and browsers which support CSS3 will use them.

Answer (score 3):

You can have progressively-enhanced CSS by using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/):

> Modernizr is a JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and CSS3 features
>   in the user’s browser.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Conditional CSS](http://www.conditional-css.com)?

It runs server side and lets you put conditions in your CSS code 
here's an Example from the project's website:

```
body {
    font: 90%/1.45em "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
}

[if IE].container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;

    [if gte IE 7]background: url('ie7.png') no-repeat center center;
    [if lte IE 6]background: url('ie.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}

[if Webkit].container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: -125px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    padding-top: 180px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    background: url('webkit.png') no-repeat center 30px;
    background-color: #eee;

    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #555;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

[if Opera].container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding-top: 140px;

    background: url('opera.png') no-repeat center 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

[if Gecko].container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -150px;

    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 2em;

    background: url('moz.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-color: #ddddff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for Internet Explorer with conditional comments, for example:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    // IE6
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    // IE8 or below
<![endif]-->
```

For other browsers, you will have to use JavaScript. (Hint: try using `navigator.userAgent`, which on my computer is `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36"`.) For more information, [see this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html).

Comment: IE 10 removed this feature

Answer (score 0):

You need the [navigator](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp) object for this

Answer (score 0):

For Internet explorer you can add this inside the head html tag:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
...include IE6-specific stylesheet here...
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
...include IE7-specific stylesheet here...
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    // IE8 or below
<![endif]-->
```

For mozilla you can add this to your stylesheet to specify css code only for mozilla browser

```
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
}

/***** Selecor Hacks ******/

/* IE6 and below */
* html #uno  { color: red }

/* IE7 */
*:first-child+html #dos { color: red } 

/* IE7, FF, Saf, Opera  */
html>body #tres { color: red }

/* IE8, FF, Saf, Opera (Everything but IE 6,7) */
html>/**/body #cuatro { color: red }

/* Opera 9.27 and below, safari 2 */
html:first-child #cinco { color: red }

/* Safari 2-3 */
html[xmlns*=""] body:last-child #seis { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:nth-of-type(1) #siete { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:first-of-type #ocho {  color: red }

/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #diez  { color: red  }
}

/* iPhone / mobile webkit */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #veintiseis { color: red  }
}

/* Safari 2 - 3.1 */
html[xmlns*=""]:root #trece  { color: red  }

/* Safari 2 - 3.1, Opera 9.25 */
*|html[xmlns*=""] #catorce { color: red  }

/* Everything but IE6-8 */
:root *> #quince { color: red  }

/* IE7 */
*+html #dieciocho {  color: red }

/* Firefox only. 1+ */
#veinticuatro,  x:-moz-any-link  { color: red }

/* Firefox 3.0+ */
#veinticinco,  x:-moz-any-link, x:default  { color: red  }



/***** Attribute Hacks ******/

/* IE6 */
#once { _color: blue }

/* IE6, IE7 */
#doce { *color: blue; /* or #color: blue */ }

/* Everything but IE6 */
#diecisiete { color/**/: blue }

/* IE6, IE7, IE8 */
#diecinueve { color: blue\9; }

/* IE7, IE8 */
#veinte { color/*\**/: blue\9; }

/* IE6, IE7 -- acts as an !important */
#veintesiete { color: blue !ie; } /* string after ! can be anything */
</style>
```

Comment: IE 10 removed this feature.

Comment: I'm guessing for IE10 he wont need that, only for older versions, because IE10 sucks less i guess :)

Comment: Ah ok that has worked for mozilla thanks....is ther any other code like this for chrome, safari etc?

Comment: Here you go i edited the Answer i hope it helps or look at http://browserhacks.com/ for more

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via PHP using $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

It is also possible to target IE browser via HTML : 
Try:

```
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_style_ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_style_ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```

Or within the CSS file see overflow question: 
[Apply CSS rules if browser is IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541982/apply-css-rules-if-browser-is-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mozilla") > 0 )
        $(".titleAreaBox").css("margin-top", changed_value);

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 0 )
        $(".titleAreaBox").css("margin-top", changed_value);

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > 0)
        $(".titleAreaBox").css("margin-top", changed_value);

    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") > 0 ) 
        $(".titleAreaBox").css("margin-top", changed_value);

});
```

Comment: Ah ok, is there a way to instead of going to a different css file. Reference a class on the page, and then change it dependant on the browser?

Comment: yeah there is! just check it out in a minute or two!

Comment: @CallumHolden check it out now!

Comment: for example i am trynig to set the margin-top position, so that it is the same in all browsers. I need to change it now for chrome....how would I do this?

Comment: and also what is target_object?

Comment: so what I have is a class called titleAreaBox, what I want to be able to do is change the margin-top property within this class using your method?

Answer (score 0):

As someone else mention, Modernizr is ideal for this.  Checking for browser version isn't recommended anymore. Instead you should test for functionality that is needed. You can use a library like Modernizer to aid you in this.

EG: To check for geolocation functionality you can use this check:

```
if (Modernizr.geolocation) { 
    //your code 
}
```

If you are checking browser version, odds are you are looking to get a certain piece of functionality out of it, like geolocation or AJAX (IE uses different libraries to accomplish this over its lifetime for some reason).