# Modifying jQuery selector for cross browser grayscale filter

Tags: css, debugging, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-11

Looking to use [this](http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-ie11/) cross browser grayscale filter and had it working on all images, but I want to restrict the effect to the images within a single div.

In function.js I changed all instances of the selector from `grayscale($('img'));`
 to `grayscale($('#grayscale-div img'));` and did so in all instances. It's adding the CSS class, but in IE11 the effect doesn't work anymore.

I'm trying to see if this is a mistake I'm making with the jQuery selector. Thanks for in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Code Excerpt:

```
if (getInternetExplorerVersion() >= 10){
    $('#grayscale-div img').each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        el.css({"position":"absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass('img_grayscale').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"5","opacity":"0"}).insertBefore(el).queue(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            el.parent().css({"width":this.width,"height":this.height});
            el.dequeue();
        });
        this.src = grayscaleIE10(this.src);
    });

    // Quick animation on IE10+ 
    $('#grayscale-div img').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 200);
        }, 
        function () {
            $('.img_grayscale').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 200);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getInternetExplorerVersion()` conditional check is failing in IE11. The following change:

```
if(getInternetExplorerVersion() >= 10 || !!window.MSInputMethodContext)
```

will fix it in the code shown above. Here are some unrelated questions which explain the problem and the solution:

- [How to detect IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11/22082397#22082397)
- [Detecting IE11 using CSS Capability/Feature Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-properties/22085005#22085005)