# detect IE11 without JavaScript in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have been using the following trick to make browser-specific HTML:

```
<!--[if (IE)]>  <div class= "ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE)]><!--> <div class= "not_ie"> <!--<![endif]-->
</div>
```

This does not work with IE11. Any new tricks to use?

I can detect it using JavaScript:

[Detecting IE11 using CSS Capability/Feature Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-properties)

or

```
Object.hasOwnProperty.call(window, "ActiveXObject") && !window.ActiveXObject)
```

but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I'm using a font, gabriola, which is displayed differently in IE (it's not vertically centered in then element). I therefore add some extra margins. I don't really think that using this font is considered bad code, but you're entitled to your opinion, of course.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes unless you're writing an IE deprecation text and only want to show it to IE users (my situation). We will not support IE (all versions) and need to show a warning message to those poor people.

Comment: @Spock but for that goal JS UA based detection works just fine. My comment 5 years ago applied to IE11-specific rendering exceptions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IE 11 does not longer support conditional comments in your HTML code. So you have to use Javascript.

[Microsoft Dev Center - IE 10+ Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)