# CSS for IE 11 only

Tags: css

i need to fix a bug which is breaking my layout in IE 11.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<![endif]-->
```

is not supported after IE 9.

Using java script is a least preferred method, is their another way to go about doing this?

Comment: Your question is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-properties

Comment: Not helpful, i just fell back to javascript. I suggest everyone with this issue do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments do not work in IE10/IE11.

I think the ideal solution is to understand why you need the IE detection, and work to find a solution that doesn't require any browser detection. IE11 is actually (and finally!) pretty good at modern web standards, so I think you don't need to detect it.

Comment: I clearly said that it was not supported after IE 9, and i clearly said that it is breaking my Layout therefor i must say you did not read my description of my issue at all. Though IE11 is better than its predecessors, it does not mean it a 'pretty good webbrowser'. -1

Comment: Agree, IE css engine don't update max-height property correctly over window resize. Had to do it with javascript, it is better, but still not good