# Is their any replacement for <Fieldset> tag

Tags: input, fieldset, disable

I want to disable all the form fields based on some condition. I decided to use Fieldset tag in HTML which is simple. But i came to know its not supported in IE.

Please let me know is their any other solution for this.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119329/fieldset-and-disabling-all-child-inputs-work-around-for-ie

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fieldset and disabling all child inputs - Work around for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119329/fieldset-and-disabling-all-child-inputs-work-around-for-ie)