# How to write css for alt attribute of img tag (word-break: break-all property doesn't work in IE)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, dojo

I have a img tag inside anchor tag. ancher tag is inside a div tag. I am using alt attribute of img tag. Value of alt attribute is a text of length 68 character. My Problem is alt attribute value(text) is going outside of div & it is hidden in IE. I mean after displaying few characters normally rest characters are hidden or cropped. Here is my html code snippet.

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="prod-image"  id="catEntryImage">
        <div class="prodClass" id=WCCE>
           <a><img alt="some text total around 70 character" src="someURL"/></a>
           <P class=gasCode></P>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="prod-content"></div>
   <script type="text/javaScript"></script>
</div>
```

CSS for given html snippet

```
div {
    line-height: 1.4em;
    word-break: break-all;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}

img {
    text-decoration: none;
    border:0;
}

a {
    color: #e10014;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.products .prod-image {
    width: 135px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.products .prod-content {
    width: 288px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I applied word-wrap & line-break css property to alt attribute of image but it also didn't work. Can any body help me with this? This is happening only in IE. If I use "word-break: break-all" css property for img tag than its works fine in chrome but doesn't work in IE.

Comment: can you please provide html code here.. so that we can more identify your problem.

Comment: I have provided html & css snippet above.

Comment: Which `IE` as its working fine here on `IE11` and `IE10`.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Its IE 11. Please check now I have updated complete html snippet structure above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to set a `height` and `width` on the parent of the image which is `.prodClass` and also set `height` and `width` on the `<img>`
The alt should take care of itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lu3tu98b/5/

```
<div class="prodClass">
     <a>
        <img alt="This will contain a really long sentence with more than 70 characters right here." src="someURL"/>
    </a>       
</div>

.prodClass {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: wheat;
}

.prodClass img {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Updated the example in IE 11

Answer (score 1):

Please go through my [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/gqdmqm4e/8/)   , I hope this is the exactly what you're trying to achieve.

I've create two separate `images` with large `alt` text.

`HTML`:

```
<a class="a1"><img alt="some text total around 70 character some text total around 70 character some text total around 70 character some text total around 70 character some text total around 70 character" src="someURL"/></a>

<a class="a2"><img alt="some text total around 70 character some text total around 70 character some text total around 70 character some text total around 70 character some text total around 70 character" src="someURL"/></a>
```

`CSS`:

```
.a1{
     text-decoration: none;
    border:0; 
    width:270px; 
    word-break:break-all; 
    height:auto;
    display: block;
   }

.a2{
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 0px none;
   width: 270px;
   word-break: break-all;
   height: auto;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: block;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

On First `image` , I've used `word-break:break-all` to break and wrap the `alt` text within the `img` wrapper. Whereas on the later one I've used `text-overflow:ellipsis` to hide the extra `alt` text when its exceeding the `img` wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

use this.

```
img{width:100px} // change this as per you requirement
```

this should trick the IE problem..

also specify this in the IE only style. so will not affect other browser working..

Like:

```
 <!--[if IE]><style type="text/css"> img{width:100px}</style><![endif]-->
```

To deal with IE 11 issue: please refer this [`old post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-properties)

Comment: Please specify version of IE, i think you are taking about IE 11, it is a new challenge, I have update a link of old post in my answer to deal with IE 11

Comment: If I don't keep background color in css then it is showing a border on div. I kept border: none; but still it is showing border. Is there any way to remove this border?

Comment: it must be image border, do the same to image `img{border:none;}` OR `img { border-width: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

just style

```
img { color: red; }
```

for the alt tag text styling

Comment: your suggestion works fine for changing color of text inside alt attribute but my problem is text is not wrapped in parent div so most of the characters are not being displayed or I must say alt tag value is hidden.