# Link CSS EXCEPT IE 10,11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, import, hyperlink

now I know, that `<!--[if !IE]><!-->...<!--<![endif]-->` doesn´t work for IE 10+.

So there is one option, to use:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    // IE10+ CSS here
}
```

but I need something like this:

```
@media all and not(-ms-high-contrast: none), not(-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    // every browser EXCEPT IE10+ CSS here
}
```

It is possible?

Thx.

Comment: Does any of the answers to [Detecting IE11 using CSS Capability/Feature Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18907131/1016716) help? (Or, any of the questions in its Linked list.)

Comment: @MrLister sadly no, I am trying to avoid javascript. But that is not the main problem, only way in thread that souhld work for me is tagged solution, but it has on big problem - in doesn´t recognize if it is Edge or IE, for that solution it is same browser.

Comment: The accepted answer uses JavaScript, yes, but there are many other answers to that question, including newer ones. I mean, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45494070/1016716) looks nice. `@supports not (old: ie) { /* code for not old IE here */ }` is just what you want. See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40supports#Examples).

Comment: Did not notice that answer, that is brilliant and works for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MrLister I have solution to my problem.

pack your css to this and it will work.

```
@supports not ((-ms-high-contrast: none) or (-ms-high-contrast: active)) {...}
```