# Custom HTML Embedded SVG animation not working in IE 11?

Tags: html, animation, svg, internet-explorer-11, webflow

I am using webflow and embedded a custom HTML SVG animation into the background of the page. Works great in everything but internet explorer 11. How can I fix this so that it works across all browsers?

I tried putting some CSS code into the page to detect if it was in internet explorer 11, but I am not very familiar with CSS and it just made the waves disappear.

https://proj-24e99d.webflow.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would there be a way to detect if a user is using IE 10 or IE 11 so
>   that it could display the animation as a single image that covers the
>   page, but otherwise use the wave animation?

You could use the following code to detect the browser version:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font: 1.25em sans-serif;
        background-color:palegreen;

    }
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        /* IE10+ specific styles go here */
        body{
            background-color:aqua;
        }
    }
</style>
```

More details, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-capability-feature-detection).

Besides, about the SVG animation, as a workaround, I think you could try to use a .GIF file to display the animation (the wave), set it as the background image.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know IE 10 and 11 only support animation with programmatic scripting.
Hope the below links below understand more.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/gg193979(v=vs.85)

Comment: Okay I think I understand. Would there be a way to detect if a user is using IE 10 or IE 11 so that it could display the animation as a single image that covers the page, but otherwise use the wave animation?