# I can't find a solution to display my site developed in css grid on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, grid, css-grid

I developped a website portfolio with css grid but this css property is doesn't work on IE.

I tried to use Autoprefixer with scss but without success. I also tried to change the display of the website to warn IE users that this site is not adapted to this browser.

I expect find the best solution for IE browser

Comment: Before using any CSS property, it is always wise to check its compatibility between browsers. https://caniuse.com/#css-grid. In this case, instead of forcing the user to use a modern browser (using a message), even if appropriate and recommended, you can create both: a message and an adapted website version.

Comment: I use caniuse and I knew before starting my development that I would have difficulties with IE. It is indeed conceivable that I develop a specific version for IE, however, it does not answer my question how to change the content depending on the browser

Comment: Sure. There are plenty of CSS rules you can use. Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27315792/8598108

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As Azametzin said, you could use CSS rules to detect browsers, Besides, I think you could also [detect Microsoft Edge (Chromium), Chrome, IE Browser uses JavaScript](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/edde0150-9478-4ca6-ba0f-9e084b5a4719/how-to-detect-microsoft-edge-chromium-chrome-ie-browser-using-javascript?forum=iewebdevelopment).