# Looking for a Modernizr feature set to target specific minimum browser requirements

Tags: javascript, html, css, modernizr

I'm currently upgrading a website for a customer. Current website uses a Modernizr feature set to target specific browsers that we can validate works with the wide variety of customers.

Current browser minimum requirements for this website are:

- IE 10
- Firefox 19
- Chrome 32
- Safari 9
- iOS 8
- Android 4.4 (I don't bother about all the differents quirks of some Blink implementations)

Since the website is targeted for an older audience which has not a lot of IT knowledge, I am considering to still support IE11 for those who still stay on Windows 7, and Firefox 52 for those on XP.

So, new browser minimum requirements would be something like

- IE 11
- Edge all versions
- Firefox 52+
- Chrome 69+
- iOS 12+
- Android 5+

I was searching for a set of features that are known to work on all these conditions so I can set a Modernizr feature set script to redirect users to a fallsafe version of the website if needed.

I've seen this post: [Detecting IE11 using CSS Capability/Feature Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-capability-feature-detection), but it only targets IE11 (it's a great start tho). I also took a look at Caniuse but this can be kind of confusing.

My current idea is to set a feature set containing ES5 full support and ES6 minimal support, but I want to be sure to nake it OK to not have false positives on user's browsers. I also considered detecting flexbox support, since I use it.

So, considering this, would you have an idea of a feature set I could use for that specific set of browser requirements?

Edit: I wonder if there is a tool around that you can specify some browser features you want and that automatically gets you minimal browser requirements. I don't know why but I have a doubt this would probably exists somewhere.

Regards.

Comment: Aren't there sites where you can get this information from? For instance, mdn has a [browser compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Browser_compatibility), and there are several sites like [this](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) and [this](https://caniuse.com/#search=es6). Asking for a tool, service, library is off-topic here.

Comment: I already know those. I just wonder if there is a "all-features" tool compatibility list somewhere. Like, you can on Caniuse look for a specific feature, but maybe there is somehow a way to specify more that 1 feature and still get a compatibily list.

Comment: So... that is off-topic here. See [What can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Just use a js framework like jquery to abstract away compatibility issues, then when complete test using a tool like browserstack on the minimum required browsers. If done correctly you'll have a handful of changes to make towards the end of development.