# @supports CSS alternative for Internet Explorer browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

While building my personal website, I have come to a stage of making it as much cross browser compatible as I can. Where ever I could, I added "backup" styles line before a default style:

```
.selector {
  position: flex; /* backup style */
  position: grid; 
}
```

But, on my header, I need a `position: sticky`. Internet Explorer [doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) it. So I've thought using `@supports not (position: sticky)`. I tried it but it didn't work. I was sure that it should work as it should be support for all browsers! Not after I [visited caniuse.com again](https://caniuse.com/#search=%40supports).

---

The reason why I specifically need to use `@supports` and not only use `position: fixed` before `position: sticky` as a backup is because I also need to set a top margin to other content so it would appear the same:

```
@supports not (position: sticky) {
  header {
    position: fixed;
  }

  .content {
    margin-top: 500px;
  }
}
```

I have also read this thread [Detecting IE11 using CSS Capability/Feature Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907131/detecting-ie11-using-css-capability-feature-detection#27315792) which doesn't really help in my case.

Is there other, alternative way to change style to multiple elements based on if browser doesn't support `position: sticky`?

Comment: I think your best bet here is to use media queries for ie. You can find out more here:[How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet)

Comment: @JayNyxed Thank you for your reply. I will try with those methods and will close my question as duplicate if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your stylesheet for missing `position: sticky` support, then undo those changes and apply `position: sticky` in a positive `@supports`:

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 500px;
}

@supports (position: sticky) {
  header {
    position: sticky;
  }

  .content {
    margin-top: 0;  /* or whatever it was before */
  }
}
```

Comment: IE doesn't support [@support](https://caniuse.com/#search=%40supports). This is part of the question =)

Comment: @JayNyxed: So it ignores the `@supports` block and receives `position: fixed` with a margin, as intended.

Comment: @JayNyxed This does actually work. It's reversed, IE would use `position: fixed` and afterwards modern browsers who **support** `position: sticky` would overwrite fixed. Big brain, well done!