# Ignoring css in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer

There is a way to ignore files/css in ie by this statement

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <script src="js/ie_html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Is there any another way to to ignore css in ie

I want to create whole different css for ie only but other css that are not rendering pages properly in ie i want to ignore them.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can also use `<!--[if !IE]-->` and such. Check out [this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for more examples

Answer (score 2):

As I've got from this question, this issue was discussed at the following link

[Apply CSS rules if browser is IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541982/apply-css-rules-if-browser-is-ie)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
var script='<!--[if IE]>'+'<script src="js/ie_html5.js"></script>'+'<![endif]-->';
var test = document.createElement('script');
test.type = 'text/javascript';
test.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.example.com/test.js';

var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
if(isIE){
        console.log(test);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(test);
}
else{
}

};
```

or

```
<!--[if IE]>
   You're using IE!
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
   You're using something else!
<![endif]>
```

You can find documentation on the conditional comments [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/).