# Redirect on Browser Versions

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "BrowserErrorPage.php";
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

I have managed to find out if its IE7 then redirect to somepage. what if i want something like i want to redirect to error page if the IE browser version is below IE version 8.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541982/apply-css-rules-if-browser-is-ie and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567561/how-do-i-do-ie-conditionals-in-css

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "BrowserErrorPage.php";
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

For further information: [Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "BrowserErrorPage.php";
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Conditional comments are a terrible idea but here is how it would work.

Comment: why is it a terrible idea. if so what is the best solution