# Put browser specific condition in CSS selector

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have following css selector

```
 body
 {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: "Arial" ;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 25px;

  }
```

I want to write condition that if the browser is IE then change the `line-height` to 10px

I searched one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567561/how-do-i-do-ie-conditionals-in-css) but when i add the condition like mentioned in the question
it throws syntax error `Missing property name before colon(:)`. I followed question and modified code like

```
    .bodyClass
    {
      margin: 0;
     font-family: "Arial";
     font-size: 18px;
     line-height: 25px;

     <!--[if IE 6]>
       line-height: 10px;     
     <![endif]-->

   }
```

How to write the conditional statement inside css selector? I dont want to create different style sheets for IE and rest of browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

```
*line-height:10px;  //* is hack for IE7
line-height:10px\0/;  //\0/ is hack for IE8
line-height:10px\9; //\9 is hack for IE9
//below is the hack for chrome and safari browsers 
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{
    line-height:10px;
}
```

Comment: I have tried using line-height: 25px\9;  but it gives syntax error

Comment: `CSS` validator will show error but will work while loading in IE9

Comment: I used but nothing changes

Comment: using the hack media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
worked for me. I also used hack for IE 10 i.e media screen and (min-width:0\0) . Although it is not good solution but is currently working. I will try to see if i can implement solution give by . Many thanks Kishori

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to create separate stylesheets then you have two alternatives.

#### IE conditional comments

Use conditional comments to give classes to the `<html>` tag, for example:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

This way you can then use nice self-describing selectors like this in your CSS:

```
html.ie6 .bodyClass { line-height: 10px}
```

#### CSS hacks

Another option is to use appropriate [CSS hacks](http://browserhacks.com/) to target the browsers you are interested in. The advantage of this approach is that it can be done without touching the HTML/DOM at all. One specific hack that targets only IE 6 while still being syntactically valid CSS is:

```
.bodyClass { _line-height: 10px; /* hack targeting IE 6 only */ }
```

If you *do* decide to use CSS hacks, please make sure to accompany them with comments that describe what they do to help future maintainers.

Comment: I'd add that there's no guarantee whatsoever that hacks target *only* the intended browser. It just happens to be that way which people figured out over time, but this may change with future browser development.

Comment: I tried using your statements but whatever i write inside those if conditions it shows as comment in my html

Comment: @Happy: They *are* HTML comments, so that's normal: it's what they look like. But they make a difference to IE.

Comment: Is it possible to show demo? I will really appreciate it. if possible can you modify this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/84pQM/4/

Comment: @Happy: [Here's one](http://jsfiddle.net/ryRR8/), but of course you 'll need IE6 to see anything.

Comment: @Jon but i dont see any difference in output in IE and chrome. I am using IE 10 but i need this for IE9 and above

Comment: @Happy: Please read the answer carefully. Your example specifically targeted IE6, so that's what mine does too. To target IE9 and above you will have to do things in reverse: use a universally applicable style and "undo" it with another that only applies to IE <= 8.

Comment: Please show me how to apply for only IE9 and above. I really request you

Comment: Also my example was not for IE6. It was for IE9.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38969/discussion-between-happy-and-jon)

Comment: @Happy: You example certainly was for IE6; it still is: `[if IE 6]`. For the IE9 version I have already explained how to do it.

Comment: @Jon  I really have not understand what you meant for IE9?

Comment: @Jon this is my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ryRR8/10/
you can see i have added condition at top if IE greater 9. But still nothing prints inside that if condition and nor i get green background color. What is wrong here now?

Comment: @Happy: Please think longer about what you are doing. Your HTML starts with `<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <div class="ie6">` -- how does that make sense? If you see IE >= 9 then show something with class `ie6`? You also cannot target IE > 9 because IE 10 does not support conditional comments anymore. That's why I said you have to do it in reverse, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VW24g/). I hope that's enough examples, I can't write your code for you.

Comment: @Jon but i use IE 10.so that means it will look same in both in IE and chrome because IE 10 doesnt support conditional comments. So then how could i solve my issue then

Comment: @Happy: I have no idea what your issue is, and can't spend more time on this right now.

Comment: @Jon Also i updated your fiddle again to see what is being printed. But nothing gets printed in both IE 10 and chrome http://jsfiddle.net/KA24H/3/    I am really sorry if you are annoyed with me

Comment: @Jon i certainly think you will help me out. My issue is quite simple that i need different styles for IE 10 and chrome

Comment: @Happy: That fiddle was wrong, I edited the link in the meantime. See the new one.

Comment: @Jon Please paste in new fiddle. I think you forgot

Comment: @Jon Many thanks for putting so much efforts on me. I accepted Kishori's answer as workaround untill i figure out how to use your solution. Can you put the new fiddle which you said you have modified. Dont be upset with me please.

Answer (score 1):

You can write them inside headers and there join a stylesheet such as

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link href="~/folder/file.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

Else if you can use a serverside such as ASP.NET and by Using `Request.Browser` check whether if its IE and change the style.

Answer (score 0):

```
#testdiv
{
height:300px;
width:100%;
line-height:50px;
line-height:100px\9;    
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/84pQM/)

Comment: I have tried using line-height: 25px\9;  but it gives syntax error

Comment: @Happy check the fiddle on IE

Comment: I modified your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/84pQM/4/
but i get same result. The fiddle i created is same as my actual code

Answer (score 0):

Try `<!--[if lte IE 6]>`

Or you could try the opposite and add the line height as 10 then use

`<!--[if !IE]>--> 
    do something; IE will ignore this, other browsers parse it 
    <!--<![endif]-->`

to set the line height for other browsers.

Below is a link to Supporting IE with CSS

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/supporting-ie-with-conditional-comments/

Another Useful site is http://css3please.com/ which shows you the different CSS for *IE*, *Chrome* and *Firefox*. It also allows you to edit the site in real time.

Comment: The link to dev.opera.com is broken. It's backed up at https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera-static-backup/blob/master/http/dev.opera.com/articles/view/supporting-ie-with-conditional-comments/index.html