# Apply background color to text box specific to IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-color

I am new to CSS and need help with the below.
I am required to apply the below background color (i.e 255 255 255) for all browsers except IE in the below css snippet.
And for IE , i am required to apply a background color as 33,33,33.
I have tried certain CSS hacks with \0 , _ etc , but none seem to be working.
Any help please!

```
input[type="file"] {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
}
```

Comment: Please can you include full code (HTML and CSS) which reproduces the problem you are having, your current code does not appear to be attempting to target IE in a special way. Any particular reason why you want IE to look different from the other browsers? Are you trying to target particular versions of IE or all versions?

Comment: Check this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567561/how-do-i-do-ie-conditionals-in-css